# Making compost using regular soil or specific soil

Tags: compost

I have a garden in my house and some open space which has normal earth where I plant some trees.. To make compost do I have to mix the biodegradable material with a specific kind of soil or can I use any soil to mix.. The soil I have is a bit sandy good enough to grow a mango tree.. While my garden has a lawn which I assume is more compact soil where I plant trees is a bit sandy

Comment: You don't actually need to add soil to a composting system, but I'm not sure whether you're asking what you should add to the soil prior to planting your trees, or how to make a good composting system.

Comment: Hi bamboo. Thank you for your inputs.. I was reading that while making compost you mix your brown and green components with some soil especially when you are making compost in those boxes where you don't need to turn the mixture regularly.  It said just mix your vegetable wastes with the microbial soil and leave it.. What you are guiding is then that I just mix the Brown and green components with some soil to bind..

Comment: Or I don't need any soil to be added at all to make compost

Comment: Are you talking about a bokashi composting system, or other specific composting system for kitchen scraps, rather than an ordinary compost pile out in the garden, either in a compost bin or just in a heap? Not sure what you mean by 'those boxes'...

Answer (score 1):

Compost is made of vegetal waste, leaves, small branches, straw, sawdust, manure, human waste, and usually any organic matter that is decomposed by various microorganisms. The purpose of making compost is adding it to any kind of soil in order to improve its composition, to aerate it and to provide good water drainage.

Comment: Thanks alina.. But while making compost do I mix the vegetal waste with some soil to compost or just mix the brown and green components

Comment: Don't mix with soil, only the organic stuff, whatever colour it is, including coffee filters if you want. From time to time you have to turn the mix with a fork or something to aerate it.

Comment: @Fuadkidwai You're most welcome :)  By the way, did you notice the tag menu in the upper side of the page? If you click on the compost tag, you'll see what other users asked about compost. Maybe you'll find something interesting among them. https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compost